# How do I rotate the view around an object, instead of the middle point?

Tags: 3d-view

When I use the middle mouse button, the view rotates around `[0, 0, 0]`. If I would like to select this cube and rotate the view around it, how would I do it?

[image]

Comment: Select your object and press  "Number pad ." [Numbpad period](https://highfieldtales.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/numpad.jpg) and then, use the mouse as you normally would

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works. If you post an answer I will accept it

Comment: @Emir If afterwards I would like to reset it to the `[0,0,0]` position, how would I do it?

Comment: in the Preferences > Navigation > Orbit & Pan, have you enabled Orbit Around Selection?

Comment: @moonboots thanks for replying. I didn't have that selected.

Comment: so was it not what you wanted?

Comment: @moonboots, Emir indeed answered my original question, about how to orbit around an object :). I then asked how to reset the orbit back to [0,0,0], but that's not really important :)

Comment: @AndréPena use ALT + G [SEE THIS](https://youtu.be/VeHEKmEPGy0?t=108)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select your object and press "Number pad ." ([Numbpad period](https://highfieldtales.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/numpad.jpg)) and then, use the mouse as you normally would –

Comment: For those who have no Number pad, go to Edit > Preferences > Input > Emulate Numpad