# I changed some setting and now my movement axis is relative to what angle I am at in the 3d viewer instead of relative to the object coordinates

Tags: axis

How do I undo this? What is this setting? I didn't even know how to google this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I rotate the view around an object, instead of the middle point?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260630/how-do-i-rotate-the-view-around-an-object-instead-of-the-middle-point)

Comment: Or, If by 'Movement' you mean the orientation of your transforms, maybe you've set your 'Transform Orientation' to 'View' ? https://imgur.com/a/2jNXfrI (My header's at the bottom.. yours may be at the top, of the 3D View)

Answer (score 4):

Check the *Transform Orientation* at the top of the 3D View header.

You've probably changed that to *View*, set it back to *Global*.

[image]